# Node JS Express secure route

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes

I want to have some kind of auth to make protected routes.

For example, the GET `/forecastweather` should be protected. While the GET `/generalweather` should not.

I read the express 4.x documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) but I can't find an authentication function. I also looked in the req (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) documentation to see if there is an attribute to request I can use.

If I'm right express had basic auth function, but it seems to be gone. What is the best way to protect routes by some kind of bearer token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best" way to do authentication.  There are just multiple different ways and you have to decide which fits your situation the best.

First, you need to decide how you're going to deliver your credential which likely depends upon what type of client you're using.

1. Token in a cookie (often works best for browser access)
2. Token in a custom header (often used for programmatic access for APIs)
3. Token in query parameter (not as common)

Once you decide how the token is going to be delivered, you then have to figure out how the client is going to get their token. This would typically be some sort of form submission that contains credentials (such as username and password) and the return from a successful verification of those credentials would be the token.

To process this form, you'd create a POST request handler in Express and verify the credentials, returning a token if the credentials are valid.

Then, within Express, you'd create a router that contains the authenticated routes and add some middleware to that router that verifies that a valid token is present on the request before allowing the request to proceed.  This will protect all the routes on this router.